# pthread_mutex_t as class member causes deadlock

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

I am new to parallel computing and so I am playing around with pthread and mutexes.
Running the following code leads to a deadlock. Can anybody explain me why, and how to to this in a correct way? My aim is to protect member variables from cross writing.
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

class mutex_class
{

    public:
        mutex_class();
        void print_stars(int count);
        void print_dots(int count);

    private:
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;

};

mutex_class::mutex_class()
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);
}

void mutex_class::print_stars(int count)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "*" << std::flush;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
}

void mutex_class::print_dots(int count)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&this->mutex);
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&this->mutex);
}

void* call_dots(void* m)
{
    (*(mutex_class*)m).print_dots(20);
}

void* call_stars(void* m)
{
    (*(mutex_class*)m).print_stars(20);
}

int main()
{
    mutex_class m1 = mutex_class();
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, call_dots, (void*)&m1);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, call_stars, (void*)&m1);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Did you consider upgrading your compiler (e.g. to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9.x) and using C++11 ? It has [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) etc etc.

Comment: If you are using C++, use std::thread. Way easier in some ways.

Comment: Or just fix your code. Remove the `pthread_mutex_t mutex;` in your constructor. The local var is hiding the class member, which remains uninitialized.

Comment: If you want to use C++11-style threads but can't yet use a new enough compiler, boost::thread is very similar and works well on much older systems.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is here:

```
mutex_class::mutex_class()
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;             // <<< remove this line
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL);
}
```

You're initialising a local mutex, and leaving the member variable uninitialised.

Unless you're stuck in the past for some reason, consider using the standard C++ thread library; it's more portable, and less error-prone, than mucking around with C-style APIs. Here's your program in a more C++ idiom:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class mutex_class
{
    public:
        // No need for a special constructor

        void print_stars(int count);
        void print_dots(int count);

    private:
        std::mutex mutex;
};

void mutex_class::print_stars(int count)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);  // unlocks automatically
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "*" << std::flush;
    }
}

void mutex_class::print_dots(int count)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);  // unlocks automatically
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
}

// No need to muck around with C-style 'void*' functions

int main()
{
    mutex_class m1;
    std::thread t1([&]{m1.print_dots(20);});
    std::thread t2([&]{m1.print_stars(20);});
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```